How to use the output of a command as another command (nor an argument of one) in a shell script
I need to get a value from a file where it is defined as variable1=value1.
So if I do cat file | grep variable1 I get variable1=value1.
I would like to do this inside a script so that variable1 is directly assigned value1.
I thought this might do it: cat file | grep variable1 | sh but it doesn't.
I know the same can be achieved by additional string processing and declaring variable1 explicitly inside the script, but my idea seems so elegant if I can get it to work. :) And I am 99% sure it's possible, I just can't find the missing bit.
Later edit: I should have mentioned this. The file I am trying to parse is not a script and doesn't have only such declarations. It contains all kinds of data with several syntaxes inside. It's similar to an INI/CONFIG file.

Can you source the file?

@pmf Thanks, but that file is not a script and doesn't have a syntax with only such declarations. There are various types of data in there.

cat file | grep variable1 is a "Useless Use of cat". You can replace it with grep variable1 file

Your attempt cat file | grep variable1 | sh finds all the instances of variable1 but executes them in a new shell, which then exits - so it doesn't help you.

@MarkSetchell I got it! It was this last comment that turned on the light bulb. The solution turns out to be simpler than I ever expected. export $(grep -m1 variable1 <path_to_file>) (m1 because the declaration actually shows up more than once in the file). And it works as expected. Thank you for your help.

I want to thank everyone for the support here. Each answer drove me bit by bit to the solution. In the end, it was simpler than I had expected:
declare $(grep -m1 variable1 <path_to_file>)
Using the example file.txt from the answer by @Mark Setchell:
declare $(grep -m1 a file.txt)
echo $a
3

Later edit: a previous version of this post used export instead of declare, but that is not optimal. You might need it if you want to export the variable in the environment.

Thanks for putting your solution as an answer.

Do you really want your variable to be in the environment? Otherwise, use declare instead of export.

@CharlesDuffy Thanks! Indeed, I don't. I've changed my code and will edit the answer.

Let me show you how source works:
Prompt> cat file1.txt
v1=11
v2=222
v3=33333
Prompt> source file1.txt
Prompt> echo $v1
11
Prompt> echo $v2
222
Prompt> echo "v3=$v3"
v3=33333

Have fun.

Thanks, but that file is not a script and doesn't have a syntax with only such declarations. There are various types of data in there.

@LouisNichols: that's the whole idea: the source command treat a regular file and launch it as a script, which causes lines, like var1=value1 to cause the variable var1 to get the value value1, which can be used with the dollar-sign in front of the variable's name: $var1.

Thank you. I tried that, but unfortunately it fails where the syntax rubs bash the wrong way. The script is configured with set -e, set -E and set -o pipefail, which is not up to me and is probably why it "works" (read: doesn't work) like that

Using eval or . (aka source) is very tempting for a problem like this, but is fraught with peril.  If you dynamically generate source code and evaluate it (with eval or source), you are using a very powerful foot gun.  It is safer to do something like:
$ grep variable1 input
variable1=foo
$ while IFS== read var value; do test "$var" = variable1 && variable1=$value; done < input
$ echo $variable1
foo

Using a while/do loop to read through a file is extremely slow, but if you want speed you probably shouldn't be writing this as a shell script.  If you are setting multiple values, do it all in one loop, though.

How about sourcing only lines that contain an equals sign?
Using this as file.txt:
The cat sat on the mat
# A comment
[An ini-type thing]
a=3

Then use:
source <(grep = file.txt)
echo $a
3


Thank you. That looks exactly like what I need. However, I can't seem to get it to work. There's something about the syntax. I used set -x to track what is going on. Where the line source <(grep = <path_to_file>) is, the log shows + source /dev/fd/63 . I tried various combinations of whitespace and parantheses (I am still a bit confused about some details of the syntax) but no joy.

There was a bug in an older version of bash that could break this -- which release are you trying to use? It should be fine in modern (5.x) builds.

@CharlesDuffy I have GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) so I guess that's not it. But it doesn't matter, because I found a(nother) way. See my answer below. Thank you for your help, though.
